# Real time logging to file with SSH?

Tags: perl, ssh

```
my $file = 'log.log';
my $cmd = 'sysstat';
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host);
$ssh->login('admin', 'password');

open my $in, "-|", ($ssh->cmd($cmd))[0];
open my $out_fh, ">", $file;
#print+($ssh->cmd($cmd))[0]."\n";
while (my $line = <$in>) {
    print { $out_fh } $line;
}
```

Any recommendations for how to log ssh output to a file in real time? $cmd will run forever and I'd like each line it spits out be written to the file in real time.

Comment: `$out_fh->autoflush(1);` will cause Perl to flush the output to disk when you print it, but there might be other buffering in play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with Net::SSH::Perl... well, at least not easily!

Use [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH) instead:

```
$ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host, user => $user, password => $password);
$ssh->system({stdout_file => $file}, $cmd);
```